# Screen Sharing Behind Firewall

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vnc, firewall, remote-access

I've setup my brother's computer with Ubuntu. I would like to be able to control his screen with his permission, to configure and instruct him when needed. However, he is on a provide IP provided by his router or will be at a coffee shop. Is there an easy way for him to allow me to access his computer without having to configure a router?

Thank you.

Comment: There are two ways I know of, teamviewer for linux and the [remote desktop sharing via Chrome browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en). I haven't used either so can't write a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the Chrome desktop sharing works quite well.  I've used it to help a friend with his computer problems and we were both running a flavor of Linux (him Ubuntu 12.04, me Mint 16).

Just to confirm, the Chrome Remote Desktop works through firewalls - we are both behind our home firewall/router and it works just fine.